# Doctrine / MongoDB / Strategy - Updating Documents with persist / flush

Tags: mongodb, doctrine

I am running unit tests on mongo db documents... and found that the only way I could update an existing object after finding it, was to set the ( strategy="set" ) inside the Annotations.  Does anyone know why this has to be set?  And better yet, what exactly does this change when using that setting?

Answer (score 0):

The `strategy="set"` attribute refer to the `@Collection` annotation on a property of a Document:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#collection

eg:

```
class User {

   /** @Collection(strategy="set") */
   public $tags;
}
```

The default value for strategy is `pushAll`, that will append the new values added to the `$tags` array.

With `set`, the `$tags` array will **overwrite** the value stored in the db.